# What sort of algebra is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Let us say that I have a set of symbols, $S$.

The symbols can be operated on by a set of $n$-ary operators, $O$.

**Importantly**, some of these operators are in the set of symbols, i.e. $S \cap O \neq \emptyset$.

If I am searching MathSciNet for work done with algebras that have such a flavour, what keywords should I use?

Comment: Do you have a situation where this sort of thing arises?

Comment: @Lubin In my head? Literally, and figuratively. (I promise! Or, to be clearer: biology).

Comment: I’d feel more comfortable if you had come across such things in the real mathematical world. Good luck!

Comment: @Lubin I edited my response to your question slightly in order to add more clarity; I am not sure if you caught the edit? Isn't "real mathematical world" a bit...paradoxical?

Comment: You're asking about a structure consisting of a set of symbols and a set of $n$-ary operators acting upon it? (Calling a structure an "algebra" can be a bit misleading outside of the field of universal algebra.)

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, but where the operators may themselves be symbols, and vice versa.

Comment: @user89 By $n$-ary you mean for a fixed $n$ or for various $n$?

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, don't know why I missed your comment! I mean various $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say $n$-ary trees in which each internal node can be labeled with an operator from $O$ and all leaf nodes can be operators or symbols. If the number of symbols is finite, then $S$ will be finite too, since the maximum size of $O$ is finite.  If you take a tree that has operator leaves, then it is an *operator*, and if all its leaves are filled with symbols, then what you actually have is the result of a composition of your operators, that is completed, so you do indeed have a *symbol* value.

So essentially what you have is all parse trees for a calculator with operators in $O$, lol.